# How can I return a green check mark icon when my email form script returns successfully

Tags: php, css, validation, email

I have a simple php email script. This returns a simple text message saying the email has been sent successfully. I would like to add a green check mark icon next to it.

I tried including it as an img src, but it seems the output is only recognized as pure text.

```
$responseCompleted = 'Form successfully submitted. <img src="http://www.mywebsite.be/img/vink.png"><br>';
```

So how can I add the image?

Answer (score 1):

You've got quotes in your quotes, you can't to that. You could use singles on the outside set and doubles on the inside set:

```
$responseCompleted = 'Form successfully submitted. <img src="http://www.mywebsite.be/img/vink.png"><br>';
```

Or escape the inner quotes with backslashes:

```
$responseCompleted = "Form successfully submitted. <img src=\"http://www.mywebsite.be/img/vink.png\"><br>";
```

You can't do this:

```
$foo = "this is "just" a test";
```

Or This:

```
$foo = 'this is 'just' a test';
```

But you can do this:

```
$foo = 'this is "just" a test';
```

And this:

```
$foo = "this is 'just' a test";
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, now the code passes without an error ... however the image is not displayed? Only the text part ... Any suggestions?